# Is there NSMutableDictionary literal syntax to remove an element?

Tags: objective-c, nsmutabledictionary, objective-c-literals

There is a literal syntax to add object and change object in an NSMutableDictionary, is there a literal syntax to remove object?

Comment: I haven't tried it (away from a compiler at the moment), but what happens if you try to set a value to `nil`? `dict[aKey] = nil;`

Comment: @JoshCaswell Storing nil to dictionary will cause a crash.

Comment: That's what I figured. It's too bad they didn't write  `setObject:forKeyedSubscript:` to remove if the object is `nil`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, but... :-)

This is not supported by default, however the new syntax for setting dictionary elements uses the method `setObject:forKeyedSubscript:` rather than `setObject:forKey:`. So you can write a category which replaces the former and either sets or removes the element:

```
@implementation NSMutableDictionary (RemoveWithNil)

- (void) setObject:(id)obj forKeyedSubscript:(id<NSCopying>)key
{
   if (obj)
      [self setObject:obj forKey:key];
   else
      [self removeObjectForKey:key];
}

@end
```

Add that to your application and then:

```
dict[aKey] = nil;
```

will remove an element.

Comment: <insert warning about clobbering framework methods with categories> Wish it had been written this way in the first place!

Comment: @JoshCaswell - Wondered who might raise that. *Officially* Apple don't encourage this, but use it themselves to replace methods... What must be avoided is replacing the same method using different categories, then all bets are off as to which method gets called; but until Apple stop the practice themselves this should work fine. You can set the environment variable `OBJC_PRINT_REPLACED_METHODS` to `YES` to see all the methods that are replaced in this way (in Xcode set it in the scheme).

Comment: Excellent question and answer!

Answer (score 3):

No. There is not. I have tried to find proof link but did not succeed :)

Comment: You can link the LLVM page that lists all the literals.

Answer (score 2):

As of iOS 9 and macOS 10.11, these two are equivalent:

```
 [dictionary removeObjectForKey:@"key"];
 dictionary[@"key"] = nil;
```

See the [Foundation release notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/Foundation/RN-FoundationOlderNotes/index.html) (search for the heading `NSMutableDictionary subscript syntax change`).