# Check if key of NSMutableDictionary is nil

Tags: ios, objective-c

If got a NSMutableDictionary from Json Data

```
  NSMutableDictionary *returnedDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
```

I know that this key `returnedDict[@"data"][@"weather"][day][@"tides"]` is `NSNull` in some cases. So I get `-[NSNull objectForKeyedSubscript:]`

So I try according to this answer [How to check if an NSDictionary or NSMutableDictionary contains a key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784648/how-to-check-if-an-nsdictionary-or-nsmutabledictionary-contains-a-key) to check if it is nil or not.

```
if (returnedDict[@"data"][@"weather"][day][@"tides"]){ some code }
```

and

```
if (returnedDict[@"data"][@"weather"][day][@"tides"]!=[NSNull null]){ some code}
```

does not avoid to run {some code}

How do I check this in the right way?

Comment: key is null or value?

Comment: In general, its wise to have whatever is in the if-clause be something that evaluates to a real BOOL. Using side-effects of the language (in this case 'any non-zero value is considered YES') is less advisasable, because it might cause unexpected false-positives (like here in your case), it makes your code slightly less clear for others and your future self. Also, with Swift in the world now, it's smart to make this a habbit, as in Swift its required that any if-clause evaluates to a Bool.

Comment: The Value is an instance of NSNull

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So your issue is:

Your server may return `null` to indicate that an object isn't present. `NSJSONSerialization` will convert that `null` into an instance of `NSNull`. In theory that means that instead of doing `result[a][b][c]` you need to check whether `result[a]` is a dictionary and, if so, whether `result[a][b]` is a dictionary, etc, etc, which is repetitious and error-prone?

Perhaps the easiest thing might be to remove from the dictionary any key with a value of `NSNull`, so that next time you ask for the value you'll get an ordinary `nil`, which is safe to message per the usual compound-messaging rules?

`NSJSONSerialization` won't do that for you but it's easy enough to add after the fact:

```
@interface NSDictionary(RemoveNullValues)
- (NSDictionary *)ty_collectionWithoutNullValues;
@end

@interface NSArray(RemoveNullValues)
- (NSArray *)ty_collectionWithoutNullValues;
@end

[...]

@implementation NSDictionary(RemoveNullValues)

- (NSDictionary *)ty_collectionWithoutNullValues {

    NSMutableDictionary *reducedDictionary = [self mutableCopy];

    // remove any keys for which NSNull is the direct value
    NSArray *keysEvaluatingToNull = [self allKeysForObject:[NSNull null]];
    [reducedDictionary removeObjectsForKeys:keysEvaluatingToNull];

    // ask any child dictionaries to do the same; note that it's safe
    // to mutate reducedDictionary in this array because allKeys is a 
    // copy property; what you're iterating is not reducedDictionary 
    // but a snapshot of its keys when the array first began
    for (id key in [reducedDictionary allKeys]) {
        id child = reducedDictionary[key];
        if ([child respondsToSelector:@selector(ty_collectionWithoutNullValues)]) {
            reducedDictionary[key] = [child ty_collectionWithoutNullValues];
        }
    }

    return [reducedDictionary copy];
}

@end

@implementation NSArray(RemoveNullValues)
- (NSArray *)ty_collectionWithoutNullValues {
    NSMutableArray *reducedArray = [NSMutableArray array];

    for (id child in self) {
        if ([child isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) continue;

        if ([child respondsToSelector:@selector(ty_collectionWithoutNullValues)]) {
            [reducedArray addObject:[child ty_collectionWithoutNullValues]];
        } else {
            [reducedArray addObject:child];
        }
   }

   return [reducedArray copy];
}
@end
```

Comment: This solution seems to be the best, but for now I am not able to make it work in my code.

Comment: @WolfgangGiesel - If you have dictionaries inside of arrays, in any combination, which is not uncommon in JSON? If so you'll need to walk the whole JSON structure to look for the dictionaries and then apply this answer to what you find.

Comment: Yes, apologies, written extemporaneously: assumes a top level dictionary with only children that are dictionaries. It really needs expanding to handle the `NSArray` case. I'll try to edit later; marking as community wiki for now in case somebody else wants to step in.

Comment: Updated with an attempt to filter arrays too.

Answer (score 0):

You **must** read this answer in conjunction with the accepted answer *and* comments to the question [Is there NSMutableDictionary literal syntax to remove an element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22052577/is-there-nsmutabledictionary-literal-syntax-to-remove-an-element)

Following on from the linked answer you can quietly remove all the `NSNull`'s and return `nil` instead if you access the element using the literal syntax (i.e. *not* using `objectForKey:`) by adding the following to your application:

```
@implementation NSDictionary (ClobberNSNull)

- (id) objectForKeyedSubscript:(id<NSCopying>)key
{
   id result = [self objectForKey:key];
   return result == NSNull.null ? nil : result;
}

@end
```

Now when you use the syntax:

```
dictionary[key]
```

if the matching object is `NSNull` then `nil` will be returned just as if the key did not exist.

There are caveats, see the linked question, and you need to decide if this approach is suitable for your situation. But it is simple.

HTH

Note: Before someone comments, `NSNull` is a singleton so the `==` is OK.

Comment: So it appears it (a) works (b) solves the problem (c) follows an Apple pattern and (d) contains *caveat* and it earns a silent down vote? Harsh.

Comment: Disclaimer: the negative vote isn't from me. That being said: maybe the caveat that this will affect all dictionaries offended?

Comment: @Tommy - Well that is a caveat (though probably not a significant one), and maybe you're right it is what offended. Who knows?

Answer (score -1):

use 
`if(![returnedDict[@"data"][@"weather"][day][@"tides"] isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) { some code }`

Comment: This will only work if the last value is `NSNull`, if any of the other ones are `NSNull` then the application will crash.